# 360 degree gravity game mechanic like “They Need To Be Fed” game

Tags: 2d, box2d, game-physics, box2d-iphone

I am a fan of "They Need To Be Fed" game and I want to understand the game mechanic at a deeper level. What are some good resources for the basic Box2d (or similar) physics behind the 360 degree gravity game mechanic ?

First of all, I would like to understand how to make the character orbit the circle or any box without falling down using Box2d or similar physics

From my understanding, we need to set world's gravity to zero and then apply centripetal force to the character.

I have searched around the web for tutorials that ideally will answer the above questions and perhaps provide additional resources regarding efficiency, camera motion and so on but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

try using changing the gravity

```
-(void) changeGravityByxVariant:(float) xVariant andyVariant:(float)yVariant{
    world->SetGravity(b2Vec2(xVariant, yVariant));
}
```

i have tested this and it works..... Can't find anything easier